# 「脆弱性のある漏洩（公開）した Google Cloud Platform（GCP）API キーが含まれている」警告アラート

Tags: android, google-cloud, youtube-data-api, google-play

GooglePlayに公開中のアプリについて
『脆弱性のある漏洩（公開）した Google Cloud Platform（GCP）API キーが含まれている』
と指摘・警告があり、

以下サイトを参照し、下記2点の対応を加えたのですが、ひきつづき警告された状態のままで
具体的にどう対処するのが正解なのか分からない状況です。
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

同様な対応をされた方、対処方法などアドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

また、対応内容としてgradle.propertiesを利用したのですが、
アプリケーションのソースツリー内のファイルとして扱われているのでしょうか。

＊対応内容＊
＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
1)APIキーに正しく制限が掛かっていることを確認
2)以下の記述から、ソースに直書きしていたキーを、gradle.properties へ移動させ、読込みするように変更

※↓翻訳アプリで翻訳した文面です
ーーーーーーーーーーーーー
・APIキーを直接コードに埋め込まないでください。
　コードに埋め込まれているAPIキーが誤って一般に公開される可能性があります。
　たとえば、あなたが共有するコードからキーを削除することを忘れているかもしれません。
　APIキーをアプリケーションに埋め込む代わりに、それらを環境変数またはアプリケーションの
　ソースツリー外のファイルに格納します。

・アプリケーションのソースツリー内のファイルにAPIキーを保存しないでください。
　APIキーをファイルに格納する場合は、キーがソースコード管理システムに入らないようにするために、
　ファイルをアプリケーションのソースツリーの外に置いてください。
　GitHubなどの公開ソースコード管理システムを使用している場合、これは特に重要です。
ーーーーーーーーーーーーー

Answer (score 0):

gradle.propertiesがバージョン管理に含まれていたら結局APIキーがリポジトリ上にいることになるので問題は変わらないと思います。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。
ーーーーー
>gradle.propertiesがバージョン管理に含まれていたら結局APIキーがリポジトリ上にいることになるので
ーーーーー
こちらの意味は、ソースが公開されているとという意味と理解しましたが、
ソースを公開していないので、該当しないと思うのですが・・違いますでしょうか？

Comment: gradle.propertiesはリポジトリ外にあるのですね。失礼しました。